# Spring Injection: What is the correct way of using context

Tags: java, spring, guice, code-injection

I have a question about Spring Injection.

The basic tutorial tells that we should create a context in order to get beans:

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
```

However, if I create a context in every class, the bean I can get from these context contains different instance. e.g.

```
public class MyClass1 {
    public void myMethod() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        MyBean myBean1 = (MyBean)context.getBean("myBean");
    }
}

public class MyClass2 {
    public void myMethod() {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("beans.xml");
        MyBean myBean2 = (MyBean)context.getBean("myBean");
    }
}
```

Here, the myBean1 and myBean2 are two different objects although it is supposed to be a singleton.

What is the correct way of using context so that I can guarantee that I create only one context that is used by the entire system to get beans?

Is there any way to use Spring like Google Guice which uses annotation to address dependency injection?

Many thanks.

Comment: You can do it by spring annotation.Refer this http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/1.2.9/reference/beans.html

Answer (score 0):

you can always use annotation @Autowired to mark that this is a bean you want to inject in your class

Answer (score 0):

> What is the correct way of using context so that I can guarantee that I create only one context that is used by the entire system to get beans?

Call the constructor of WhateverApplicationContext only once ...

> Is there any way to use Spring like Google Guice which uses annotation to address dependency injection?

Of course there is. It is documented in the following sections of the spring reference manual:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-annotation-config

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-classpath-scanning

You can even use the same annotations for injection as you would with Guice or CDI:

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-standard-annotations

Answer (score 0):

start context once and if you would like to use it in your class implement ApplicationContextAware.

```
public Class1 implement ApplicationContextAware{

   private ApplicationContext context;

   private void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
       this.context = applicationContext;
   }
```

the method will be automatically called after context is started.

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to use Spring's `ApplicationContext` yourself to set up your application. You should let Spring's `ApplicationContext` set up the application for you.

The common pattern is to instantiate your `ApplicationContext` at your application's startup point, whether it's a `main()` method or a `ServletContextListener` (Spring MVC). You declare the beans in your context and the relationships between them, for example, injection targets. You never initialize the same context twice within the same application.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you make a separate class and make a method which takes bean name as a parameter and you can just get the bean from context and return it. So you will be getting the same instance as you are not loading the spring configuration file again and again.